# Define specific docker-compose file to use for AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Before I run [`eb create` command](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-multicontainer-migration.html#docker-multicontainer-migration.procedure), how can I tell Elastic Beanstalk to use a DIFFERENT `docker-compose` file?

For example, my project directory:

```
HelloWorldDocker
├──.elasticbeanstalk
│  └──config.yml
├──app/
├──proxy/
└──docker-compose.prod.yml
└──docker-compose.yml
```

1. My `docker-compose.yml` is what I use for local development
2. My `docker-compose.prod.yml` is what I want to use for production

Is there a way to define this configuration before running the `eb create` command from the EB CLI?

**Stating the obvious**: I realize I could use `docker-compose.yml` for my production file and a `docker-compose.dev.yml` for my local development but then running the `docker-compose up` command becomes more tedious locally (ie: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build...`). Further, I'm mainly interested if this is even possible as I'm learning Elastic Beanstalk, and how I *could* do it if I wanted to.

---

**EDIT / UPDATE: June 11, 2021**

I attempted to rename `docker-compose.prod.yml` to `docker-compose.yml` in `.ebextensions/docker-settings.config` with this:

```
container_commands:
  rename_docker_compose:
    command: mv docker-compose.prod.yml docker-compose.yml
```

> **>eb deploy**:

```
2021-06-11 16:44:45    ERROR   Instance deployment failed.
  For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2021-06-11 16:44:45    ERROR   Instance deployment: Both 
  'Dockerfile' and 'Dockerrun.aws.json' are missing in your
  source bundle. Include at least one of them. The deployment
  failed.
```

In **eb-engine.log**, I see:

```
2021/06/11 16:44:45.818876 [ERROR] An error occurred during 
  execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build
  Application]. Stop running the command. Error: Dockerfile and
  Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment
```

Based on my testing, this is due to AWS needing to call `/bin/sh -c docker-compose config` before getting to the later steps of `container_commands`.

---

**Edit / Update #2**

If I use `commands` instead of `container_commands`:

```
commands:
  rename_docker_compose:
    command: mv docker-compose.prod.yml docker-compose.yml
    cwd: /var/app/staging
```

it **does** seem to do the replacement successfully:

```
2021-06-11 21:40:44,809 P1957 [INFO] Command find_docker_compose_file
2021-06-11 21:40:45,086 P1957 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2021-06-11 21:40:45,086 P1957 [INFO]    ./var/app/staging/docker-compose.prod.yml
2021-06-11 21:40:45,086 P1957 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2021-06-11 21:40:45,086 P1957 [INFO] Completed successfully.
```

but I still am hit with:

```
2021/06/11 21:40:45.192780 [ERROR] An error occurred during
  execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build 
  Application]. Stop running the command. Error: Dockerfile and 
  Dockerrun.aws.json are both missing, abort deployment
```

---

**EDIT / UPDATE: June 12, 2021**

I'm on a Windows 10 machine. Before running `eb deploy` command locally, I opened up Git Bash which uses MINGW64 terminal. I `cd`d to the `prebuild` directory where `build.sh` exists. I ran:

```
chmod +x build.sh
```

If I do `ls -l`, it returns:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Jarad 197121 58 Jun 12 12:31 build.sh*
```

I think this means the file is executable.

I then committed to git.

I then ran `eb deploy`.

I am seeing a `build.sh: permission denied` error in eb-engine.log. Below is an excerpt of the relevant portion.

```
...
2021/06/12 19:41:38.108528 [INFO] application/zip

2021/06/12 19:41:38.108541 [INFO] app source bundle is zip file ...
2021/06/12 19:41:38.108547 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2021/06/12 19:41:38.108556 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149125 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149142 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149190 [INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149249 [INFO] Following platform hooks will be executed in order: [build.sh]
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149255 [INFO] Running platform hook: .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149457 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks]. Stop running the command. Error: Command .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh failed with error fork/exec .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh: permission denied 

2021/06/12 19:41:38.149464 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/06/12 19:41:38.149572 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1623526898,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}

2021/06/12 19:41:38.149706 [INFO] Platform Engine finished execution on command: app-deploy
...
```

Any idea why I am getting a permission denied error?

---

## My Conclusion From This Madness

Elastic Beanstalk's EB CLI `eb deploy` command does not zip files (the `app_source_bundle` it creates) correctly on Windows machines.

#### Proof

I was able to [recreate Marcin's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880073/1577947) by zipping it locally and manually uploading it through the Elastic Beanstalk online interface. When I do that and check the source bundle, it shows that `build.sh` **does** have executable permissions (-rwxr-xr-x).

```
[root@ip-172-31-11-170 deployment]# zipinfo app_source_bundle
Archive:  app_source_bundle
Zip file size: 993 bytes, number of entries: 5
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 21-Jun-13 03:08 .platform/
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 21-Jun-13 03:08 .platform/hooks/
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx stor 21-Jun-13 03:08 .platform/hooks/prebuild/
-rwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx       58 tx defN 21-Jun-13 03:09 .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx       98 tx defN 21-Jun-13 03:08 docker-compose.prod.yml
```

When I [initialize and create](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-multicontainer-migration.html#docker-multicontainer-migration.procedure) using the EB CLI and the exact same files, `build.sh` **does NOT** have executable permissions (-rw-rw-rw-).

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-5-39 deployment]$ zipinfo app_source_bundle
Archive:  app_source_bundle
Zip file size: 1092 bytes, number of entries: 5
drwxrwxrwx  2.0 fat        0 b- stor 21-Jun-12 20:32 ./
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat       98 b- defN 21-Jun-12 20:08 docker-compose.prod.yml
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat      993 b- defN 21-Jun-12 20:15 myzip.zip
drwxrwxrwx  2.0 fat        0 b- stor 21-Jun-12 20:08 .platform/hooks/prebuild/
-rw-rw-rw-  2.0 fat       58 b- defN 21-Jun-12 20:09 .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh
```

Therefore, I think this is a bug with AWS EB CLI deploy command in regards to how it zips files for Windows users.

Comment: `commands` seemed to work because it must have run in your current working eb environemnt. `commands` executes before your zip is even extracted.

Comment: ALso, just to clarify after the updates. Everything works in EB when you provide correct file names? So the issue is how to rename docker-compose.prod.yml into docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Yes. I have a working project. It works when I have a file named `docker-compose.yml` in the root of my project. When I rename it to `docker-compose.prod.yml`, I want to configure Elastic Beanstalk to rename this file to `docker-compose.yml` at the right time in the process.

Comment: I updated the answer with my reproduction and solution to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this from command level. But I guess you could write [container_commands](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) script to **rename** your `docker-compose` file from `docker-compose.dev.yml` to `docker-compose.yml`:

> You can use the container_commands key to execute **commands that affect your application source code**. Container commands run after the application and web server have been set up and the application version archive has been extracted, but before the application version is deployed.

**UPDATE 12 Jun 2021**

I tried to replicate the issue using simplified setup with just `docker-compose.prod.yml` and `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2` 3.4.1 EB platform.

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
    client:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

I can confirm and reproduce the issue with `container_commands`. So in my tests, the **solution** was to setup [prebuild deployment hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

So my deployment zip had the structure:

```
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
└── .platform
    └── hooks
        └── prebuild
            └── build.sh
```

where

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

mv docker-compose.prod.yml docker-compose.yml
```

I also made the `build.sh` executable before creating deployment zip.

**app_source_bundle** permissions (`zipinfo -l`)

```
Zip file size: 1008 bytes, number of entries: 5
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx        0 stor 21-Jun-12 07:37 .platform/
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx        0 stor 21-Jun-12 07:37 .platform/hooks/
drwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx        0 bx        0 stor 21-Jun-12 07:38 .platform/hooks/prebuild/
-rwxr-xr-x  3.0 unx       77 tx       64 defN 21-Jun-12 07:24 .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh
-rw-r--r--  3.0 unx       92 tx       68 defN 21-Jun-12 07:01 docker-compose.prod.ym
```

Comment: I am getting a `permission denied` error. I updated my question with **EDIT / UPDATE: June 12, 2021** containing the details. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Jarad Did you make `build.sh` executable before you ziped it? chmod +x build.sh

Comment: Note of clarification: I'm not zipping it locally; I'm running `eb deploy` and it sends an `app_source_bundle` to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/` and an S3 bucket. Short answer: yes, I did make build.sh executable before running `eb deploy`. I did chmod +x build.sh. I even ran `git update-index --chmod=+x <path to file>`. When I SSH into the instance, and inspect what the file permissions are for `build.sh` (zipinfo -l app_source_bundle), it shows `-rw-rw-rw-`. I don't know if that's just because it's in a zip, or if those are really the permissions. But why?

Comment: @Jarad  I updated the question with my permissions. They are `-rwxr-xr-x ` in `app_source_bundle`. It seems that somehow your permissions are not propagated to the zip. In my test I did not use git nor eb cli.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcin. I've spent literally all day figuring this out. My take-away is, there is a bug in AWS EB CLI deploy command in how it zips files on Windows machines. I was able to recreate your example. When I used EB CLI, the same files did not work!

Comment: @Jarad Thanks. Windows could be the issue. I was using linux in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to circumvent this annoying bug by:

1. Using git and AWS CodeCommit
2. Running `git add --chmod=+x .platform/hooks/prebuild/build.sh`

This circumvents the Windows-related issue because:

> When you configure CodeCommit with your EB CLI repository, the **EB CLI**
> **uses the contents of the repository to create source bundles**. When you
> run eb deploy or eb create, the EB CLI pushes new commits and uses the
> HEAD revision of your branch to create the archive that it deploys to
> the EC2 instances in your environment.

Source: [Deploying from your CodeCommit repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli-codecommit.html#eb-cli-codecommit-deploy)

Comment: tried just about everything, CodeCommit was one of the only things to fix this.